# How to design an A/B test when homogenous variants are not obvious

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, ab-test

I would like to design an a/b test for menu for a group restaurants, which cater to online users, seeing if there is any impact on sales and orders. But the constraint is that we can only serve one different menu per day for each restaurant. On a typical day, I have about 50-60 users ordering from each restaurant.

In such a case how do I design a test given that I cant do a two different menu for each restaurant on a day? Is it good enough if I randomly sample the restaurants into control and test and tweak the menu for test?

Edit - The restaurants cater to different segments, and I plan to spread them across the variants to ensure test and control have similar types of restaurants and exclude any outliers. I could also include aggregated customer metrics for each restaurant, essentially clustering them to ensure they are homogeneous as much as I can

Comment: How different are the restaurants and their customers?

Comment: What are you a/b testing? Can a and b be on different days at each restaurant?

Comment: I want to do an a/b test to establish whether the a modification in the menu will lead to increase in metrices like orders and sale volumes. If I could serve half the customers the old menu and half of them the new one, it would have been straightforward, but cant do that

Comment: What is the difference between menus?  Is there the possibility that users from one restaraunt may go to another?

Comment: Depending on your answer to the above, a [tag:difference-in-difference] approach might be useful.

Comment: There is some overlap within the menus, but not significant, and users tend to order from multiple restaurants, so yes users-restaurants is a many to many map. Thanks, l will take a look at the difference in difference approach